# Get CALENDAR_ID to insert event in Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert an event in my Google Calendar but it is not working so far.

Is there a simple way to get the right CALENDAR_ID inside of my method?

```
 private void syncwithgooglecalendar2() {
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(CalendarSyncActivity.this).getAccountsByType(
            "com.google");
    String accountName = "";
    for (Account acc : accounts) {
        Log.d(">>>>>>>", "Name: " + acc.name + "-----Type: " + acc.type);
        accountName = acc.name;
    }
    long calID = getCalendarId(CalendarSyncActivity.this, accountName);
    ....
}

private long getCalendarId(Activity activity, String MY_ACCOUNT_NAME) {
    String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID};
    String selection = CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] selArgs = new String[]{MY_ACCOUNT_NAME};
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return TODO;
    }
    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selArgs, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getLong(0);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And the Log gives me the following infos:

```
    D/>>>>>>>: Name: email1@gmail.com-----Type: com.google
    D/>>>>>>>: Name: email2@gmail.com-----Type: com.google
    D/CalId:: 4
```

I expected another CalId, but I am not sure... 
Is there a problem when there are more than one accounts connected with the calendar? I read about "primary" but I don't know how to install this in my existing code. 
Or is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: I added the missing code above!

Answer (score 0):

Your calendarID is usually your email address. But if you have several calendars, you can use the [calendars.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method to obtain them.